# My Model Textbox is not Displayed properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

[User id Displayed answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbI8J.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2ja4.jpg)I am working on MVC 5 project in which each and every page i am getting the textbox from the model but in this page i am not able to get the textbox from the model properly....

I will explain you clearly.....

My View Page:

```
<div class="container">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Leave Application</legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @style = "color:red" })
            @Html.Raw(TempData["success"])

            @* User ID *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId,new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* User Name *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Enter UserName", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Leaves Required *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Nature of Leave *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, ViewBag.AssignRoleViewModel as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-Select-")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Start Date *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* End Date *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Reason *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Reason, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reason, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reason, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                @* Userid *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
                @* Username *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Enter Username", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
                @* Leaves Availed *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, new { placeholder = "Number of Days Required" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
                @* Type of Leave *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NatureofLeave)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, ViewBag.AssignRoleViewModel as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-Select-")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
                @* Start Date *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Startdate" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
                @* End Date *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Enddate", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate)
                </li>
                @* Reason *@
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Reason)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reason, new { placeholder = "Enter Reason for Leave" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reason, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button type="submit" id="btnLeaves" name="btnLeaves" class="btn btn-success btn-pressure">Apply</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-pressure">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My Model:

```
public class EmployeeLeave
    {
        //[Display(Name = "User Id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Leave Id")]
        public int NatureId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type of Leave")]
        public List<SelectListItem> NatureofLeave { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yy}")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yy}")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Reason")]
        public string Reason { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "No. of Leaves Required")]
        public int LeavesAvailed { get; set; }

        //public int LeavesRemained { get; set; }

        //public int TotalLeaves { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Leave()
        {
            EmployeeLeave objEmpLeave = new EmployeeLeave();
            objEmpLeave.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]);
            objEmpLeave.UserName = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);
            objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave = BindDataFromDatabaseToLeave();
            return View(objEmpLeave);
        }
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Leave(EmployeeLeave objEmpLeave)
        {
            objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave = BindDataFromDatabaseToLeave();
            var selectitem = objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave.Find(p => p.Value == objEmpLeave.NatureId.ToString());

            if (selectitem != null)
            {
                selectitem.Selected = true;
                ViewBag.Message = "NatureofLeave " + selectitem.Text;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.StartDate.ToString()))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please provide start date");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.EndDate.ToString()))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please provide end date");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave.ToString()))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Select one");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.Reason))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Reason for the Leave");
            }

            else
            {
                //objEmpLeave.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]);
                //objEmpLeave.UserName = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);
                int leaveID = objIAccountData.InsertLeave(objEmpLeave.UserId);
                int numberofleavesavailed = objEmpLeave.LeavesAvailed;

            }
            return View(objEmpLeave);
        }
```

Finally Output is:
User Id

but i require textbox beside UserId label
Here User Id is a label
The remaining pages works fine for me
Thanks in advance if you can help me alot....
I am struggling for 2 days

Comment: hi, so on the frontend you see only UserId label or you see also the value?? for exmaple User Id: 1

Comment: Hello sir, I am seeing the UserId label as well as number 1.....

Comment: Sorry, number is displayed when i click the label i.e, User Id

Comment: how is it displayed? can you make a screenshot please. i'm not able to understand you well

Comment: Definitely Sir...

Comment: Sir I doesn't know how to upload an image but the question is edited with picture showing the text "enter image description here" link

Comment: ok i saw the pic, thanks. Can you try using EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor? And why the values are not displayed, do you have any jquery code to display value on click?

Comment: I am having jQuery for calculating the end date. Start Date is picked from datepicker and No of leaves required having a textbox....... I am just adding start date with the Leaves required to get the end date that's it sir

Comment: ok. can you use EditorFor to see how it behaves instead of TextBoxFor

Comment: I already used but none.... I will send the pic again using editorfor

Comment: Sir, I posted a pic using editorfor just User ID to check whether it is working or not

Comment: i'm not able to understand how this is happening, you say that the value is there but not visible and also the textbox. I see here that using editorfor shows the control without any borders. have you tried to check your css classes, mainly the from-control & col-md-6. you can post them here so i can check. And, are you sure that that value (in your case 1 for UserId) is in the view?

Comment: I am giving my css for you sir just have a look....

Comment: form ul{
    background: white;
    margin: 0.1em;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

form li{
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

    form li:first-child {
        border-top: 0;
    }

    form li:nth-child(2) {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }

Comment: label, input, textarea {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.25em 1.2em 1em;
    outline: 0;
}

label {
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1.15em;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this please:

```
    <div class="container">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Leave Application</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @style = "color:red" })
        @Html.Raw(TempData["success"])

        @* User ID *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId,new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* User Name *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Enter UserName", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Leaves Required *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LeavesAvailed, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Nature of Leave *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, ViewBag.AssignRoleViewModel as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-Select-")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Start Date *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* End Date *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Reason *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Reason, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reason, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "from-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reason, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="submit" id="btnLeaves" name="btnLeaves" class="btn btn-success btn-pressure">Apply</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-pressure">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

with this css:

```
    form ul{ background: #eee; margin: 0.1em; border: 2px solid red; } 
    form li{ border: 2px solid #eee; border-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; 
    position: relative; } 
    form li:first-child { border-top: 0; } 
    form li:nth-child(2) { border: 2px solid #eee; }
    label, input, textarea { display: block; border: 0; } 
    input, textarea { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2.25em 1.2em 1em; 
    outline: 0; border: 2px solid #eee; } 
    label { font-size: 1em; position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 1.15em; 
    color: #000000; opacity: 1; }
```

Remove the ul element and its content and make sure that the text is not white. If text is white and background is also white then it will ofcourse not be seen.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do. but you didn't answer my questions. Are you seeing the value in frontend, for example Username: TestUser? how is it displayed?

Comment: Yes sir, I am seeing the answer for Username or userid in the front end but when i click label userid only the answer is displayed

Comment: the thing userid value is in white color i think so..... I will post a pick for this also wait sir

Comment: ok. but why it is like this, only on click? and why you are rendering Model 2 times: one as div :<div class="col-md-6">
                    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid" and one in ul:<ul>

                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { placeholder = "Enter Userid", @readonly = "readonly" })

Comment: I posted the pic have a look sir

Comment: Because i am not having 10 reputations i cannot upload more than 2 images.... So deleted one image sorry for that

Comment: Actually main thing is from <ul><li>element.... I am not getting the answer i used the bootstrap format to display it... If the bootstrap form is displayed then i would delete the ul tag or vice versa

Comment: i will udpate my answer

Comment: I am using bootstrap-tabs..... The form is not displaying properly.... I think.. I will create a new page and that page will be linked to bootstrap-tab section and i will be back when this process completes sir...

Comment: ok great. you can use the razor code that i sent to you here. it should be actually like this. if my answer helps you, then don't forget to mark it as answer :). thanks

Comment: Definitely sir i will

Comment: It is displaying as usual but the thing is I created a new page with layout null and displayed via bootstrap tabs.... Thank you very much sir

Comment: Good morning sir, I tried using another that helped me a lot. I create a new page with layout null and finally i got the answer. Shall i mark the answer with your opinion

Comment: hi, yes. i told you. it is something with the css classes (layout) that you are using in the page. as i said, if my support helped you, you can vote up and mark as answer :)

Comment: I am really sorry to say, my problem has not been solved yet.. Thank you for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Now problem has been solved!!! Thanks a lot.... You are absolutely right sir.... The problems occurs at css only

Comment: Sorry sir i am having less reputations to vote it up..... But definitely i will vote when i reach the reputations point